# Set HTTP Caching Expiration, Recommended by Google PageSpeed

Tags: php, .htaccess, caching, pagespeed

I ran tests on my website using Google's PageSpeed and it recommends that I "Leverage browser caching" and provided the following resource:

http://code.google.com/speed/page-speed/docs/caching.html#LeverageBrowserCaching

This resource never explains how to actually change the expiration date of my http headers.  Do I do this through .htaccess?  I would like to set the caching for as long as possible (without violating Google's policy of a year max).

Any advice on recommended settings (for a custom php-driven social networking community) would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

In your root's .htaccess:

```
<IfModule mod_expires.c>
  ExpiresActive On
  ExpiresDefault "access plus 1 seconds"
  ExpiresByType image/x-icon "access plus 2592000 seconds"
  ExpiresByType image/jpeg "access plus 2592000 seconds"
  ExpiresByType image/png "access plus 2592000 seconds"
  ExpiresByType image/gif "access plus 2592000 seconds"
  ExpiresByType application/x-shockwave-flash "access plus 2592000 seconds"
  ExpiresByType text/css "access plus 604800 seconds"
  ExpiresByType text/javascript "access plus 216000 seconds"
  ExpiresByType application/x-javascript "access plus 216000 seconds"
  ExpiresByType text/html "access plus 600 seconds"
  ExpiresByType application/xhtml+xml "access plus 600 seconds"
</IfModule>
```

And follow by:

```
<IfModule mod_headers.c>
<FilesMatch "\\.(ico|jpe?g|png|gif|swf)$">
Header set Cache-Control "max-age=2692000, public"
</FilesMatch>
<FilesMatch "\\.(css)$">
Header set Cache-Control "max-age=2692000, public"
</FilesMatch>
<FilesMatch "\\.(js)$">
Header set Cache-Control "max-age=216000, private"
</FilesMatch>
<FilesMatch "\\.(x?html?|php)$">
Header set Cache-Control "max-age=600, private, must-revalidate"
</FilesMatch>
Header unset ETag
Header unset Last-Modified
</IfModule>
```

This is the exact same code I use on every property I manage and offers me (and PageSpeed) the most satisfying results. One may argue on specific rules, that's why I said that it satisfies **me**, but it certainly satisfies PageSpeed.

Comment: It depends on what do you mean by "lot of conditions".
The conditions have to be processed by the web server on each HTTP request so if you think about 65,000+ conditions, then that's certainly not a good idea

Comment: Just a tip. You can just write "access plus 1 year" or even more complex directives like "access plus 1 month 15 days 2 hour" which is much easier to read and maintain than seconds.

Comment: @GeneQ, +1 for that tip. I'm used to unix timestamps, probably that's why I use seconds in the rules.

Comment: Another way to set the expiry,
ExpiresByType application/javascript A604800 
[ A604800 stands for accesstime + 604800 seconds ]

Comment: For css, does `Header set Cache-Control "max-age=2692000, public"` take over `ExpiresByType text/css "access plus 604800 seconds"`? Should be both be the same value?

Comment: why the double back slash "\\" in the FilesMatch directives? examples ( [link](http://www.askapache.com/htaccess/using-filesmatch-and-files-in-htaccess/) ) use single slash

Comment: @methode Thanks for sharing! Is this configuration still up to date?

Comment: Thanks for the great answer, are you sure we have to cashe PHP files output for 5 minutes ? I guess this will result in wrong output for dynamic applications(e.g: the clients will not see any new data like the new messages in their inbox before 5 minutes)

Comment: Why do you set different ages between `Cache-Control` and `Expires` headers ? like `2692000 seconds` and `604800 seconds` for `.css` files! . Anyway Mozilla said: ["If there is a Cache-Control header with the "max-age" or "s-maxage" directive in the response, the Expires header is ignored."](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Expires) . Another note that if I didn't set `Header set Cache-Control "max-age=2692000, public"` Apache will set the response header `Cache-Control` according to the `ExpiresByType` value . My Apache version is Apache/2.4.34 (Fedora)

Comment: why do you unset both ETag and Last-Modified? [Here](https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/performance/optimizing-content-efficiency/http-caching) says ETag is important.

Answer (score 1):

It can be done with both htaccess and php. Typically you wouldn't want to force caching the actual html since its dynamic database driven content (it can be done with the `header()` php function if needed). What you want to cache is external css & javascript, and image files.

See here for an .htaccess solution: http://www.askapache.com/htaccess/apache-speed-expires.html