# Is there a way to set Exipre headers for external JS & CSS?

Tags: facebook-graph-api, caching, http-headers, twitter, google-api

I ran Page Speed Insight on my site and Leverage Browser Caching keeps coming up because of several calls to JS's from Facebook, Twitter, Google and LinkedIn. Also Firebug shows me these resources are increasing my load time.
I've set the Expire headers as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2676744/set-http-caching-expiration-recommended-by-google-pagespeed), but still no change.

Is there something that can be done about optimizing load time & caching external resources from Google, Facebook or Twitter?

[Here](https://developers.google.com/speed/pagespeed/insights#url=adfix.ro&mobile=false&rule=LeverageBrowserCaching)'s my pagespeed report.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To answer the title question: No, there is no way of manipulating the HTTP headers for external resources, as long as you don’t want to loop them all through a proxy server of your own.