# Google Pagespeed insights claims no expiration is set, whilst it seems present

Tags: apache, caching, http-headers, pagespeed

According to [google pagespeed insights](https://developers.google.com/speed/pagespeed/insights#url=http_3A_2F_2Fchatalenka.com_2Fnew_2F_2F_3Fab&mobile=false&rule=LeverageBrowserCaching) the expiration is not set ('*(expiration not specified)*') for for example [this](http://chatalenka.com/images/_global/social-icons/delicious.png) resource. If I look at my chrome log however I see

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: Thu, 15 Nov 2012 23:27:40 GMT
Server: Apache
Accept-Ranges: bytes
Content-Length: 1323
Cache-Control: max-age=2692000, public
Expires: Sat, 15 Dec 2012 23:27:40 GMT
Keep-Alive: timeout=10, max=30
Connection: Keep-Alive
Content-Type: image/png
```

Which as far as I can see contains all the necessary headers. I am currently using the htaccess file as suggested by [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2676744/set-http-caching-expiration-recommended-by-google-pagespeed), although I tried both some manual variation and some other htaccess files as suggested by some other answers. Would anybody have any idea what I am doing wrong, or is Google simply messing with me?

Comment: Did you ever figure this out? I'm having the same issue.

Comment: @bigmike7801 Nope, never did, sorry :'(